# Using .blur(function() to update live calculation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use `.blur` to update a calculation function based off of a `select` box. It works when the user first changes the box from `0` to `1` for example, but when it's changed after that it won't reverse the previous calculation. `#to_condition` is the `id` that is displayed in text, originally `10`. After I change `#is_bent_num` from `0` to `1`, `#to_condition` is correctly decreasing by `0.5` to `9.5`, but if I change it again, say to `3`, instead of adding `0.5` back and then subtracting `1.5` (making `#to_condition` `8.5`) it subtracts `1.5` from the `9.5`, making `#to_condition = 8`.

```
var bent_num = 0.5;
var bent_orig = $("#is_bent_num").val();
$("#is_bent_num").blur(function(){
    var bent_new = $("#is_bent_num").val();
    updatecondition(bent_num * bent_orig * -1);
    updatecondition(bent_num * bent_new);
    bent_orig = bent_times;
});

function updatecondition(newcondition){
    var changecondition = $("#condition_exact").val() - newcondition;
    $("#condition_exact").val(changecondition);
    if (changecondition < 0){
        changecondition = 0;
    }
    changecondition = changecondition.toFixed(1);
    $("#to_condition").text(changecondition);
}
```

Comment: Has your question been answered?

Answer (score 1):

James, I think you didn't paste you whole code, e.g. definition of bent_times is missing. However it clearly seems for me that the first two lines of updatecondition are the cause of your problem. You should always substract from $("#is_bent_num").val() isntead of $("#condition_exact").val()

Answer (score 0):

The result put into #to_condition when the function updatecondition is called depends on both the newcondition parameter sent to the function and the #condition_exact value, and the latter is updated every time the updateconditino is called. Perhaps that update of the #condition_exact value is what is causing your problem?

```
$("#condition_exact").val(changecondition);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is here:

```
updatecondition(bent_num * bent_orig * -1);
updatecondition(bent_num * bent_new);
```

You basically update the `#condition_exact` field **twice**; once with a value based on `bent_num`, and once with a value based on the user's input (`bent_new`). The second update is (of course) the one you will see. I think what you meant to do was this:

```
updatecondition(bent_orig - (bent_num * bent_new));
```

Now the field will be updated only **once**. The new value will be the original value, minus the user's input times `bent_num`.

By the way, your variable names are a bit confusing. For example, what does `bent_num` mean? Is it the step size? Would someone else who looks at this code know what it means? (I certainly don't.) Will you, if you look at the code again in 6 months' time? So if `bent_num` is the step size, why not call it `step_size` (or `stepSize`)?